# Custom Echo Skill that allows Spotify playlist to be returned in the Directive

Tags: spotify, alexa-skills-kit

I am building an Alexa Skill that allows users to look for a particular Genre/Mood of music. I am successful in fulfilling the request and my code pulls out an appropriate playlist builds the return JSON object. The issue is in the returned directive that requests the audio streamer to kick in with the passed URL (in this case a Spotify URL). It throws an error stating there was an error opening the URL, bacause it does not directly link to a file ".mp3" for example.
I would have through if Spotify is already built into the device, it should be able to recognise Spotify URI/URL's and allow the default Spotify player to launch the link.

Has anybody else encountered the issue with using a custom app to launch a Spotify playlist/track?